# OpenMP: Compile error while declaring locks using omp_lock_t

Tags: c, openmp

I'm trying to compile an openmp program and getting the following error while compiling `error: unknown type name ‘omp_lock_t’`. I've included `omp.h` and can't figure out my mistake.

Here's my complete code:

```c
void pa1_hist_sol(int nelts, int nbins, int *__restrict__ data, int *__restrict__ hist) 
{
 int i;
 
 omp_lock_t locks[nbins];
 
 #pragma omp parallel for
 for (i=0;i<nbins;i++)
   {
     omp_init_lock(&locks[i]);
     hist[i]=0;
   }

 #pragma omp parallel for
 for (i = 0; i < nelts; i++)
   {
     int val = data[i];
     omp_set_lock(&locks[val]);
     hist[val] += 1;
     omp_unset_lock(&locks[val]);
   }

 for (i = 0; i < nbins; i++)
   omp_destroy_lock(&locks[i]);
}
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the error, `gcc -fopenmp` compiles it without a problem. What compiler and compiler flags do you use? ps: why do you use OpenMP for this code? The workload is too small, the overheads are much bigger....

Comment: ps2: You do not need locks at all, reduction (or atomic operation) is a better/faster solution...

Comment: It's an assignment where I have to use openmp. I tried both locks and atomic operations, and performance is horrible in both cases. However I'm not sure how to use reduction when it comes to arrays.

Comment: I was able to resolve the compilation issue by reinstalling the compiler.

Comment: You have to use `#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:hist[:nbins])` in the case of an array, but most probably it will not help on performance as you have to have a reasonable amount of work, otherwise it is not worth parallelizing. On the other hand this code is memory bound not computation expensive.

Comment: You should answer your own question, so others can see that your problem is solved...